# Bootstrapping repeated measure (ezANOVA)

Tags: r, lme4, anova

I want to bootstrap repeated measures anova object using the `ez` package.

```
library(ez)    

ezANOVA(data = ANT, 
        dv = rt,
        wid = subnum,
        between = group,
        within = flank, detailed=FALSE)$ANOVA
```

Output:

```
       Effect DFn DFd          F            p p<.05       ges
2       group   1  18   16.22307 7.894348e-04     * 0.2428108
3       flank   2  36 1740.31250 1.524670e-36     * 0.9841982
4 group:flank   2  36   13.01761 5.571290e-05     * 0.3178194
```

Sample data:

```
data(ANT)
summary(ANT)
```

I know that I can get the same results using `lme4::lmer()` and `parameters::parameters(model, bootstrap = TRUE)`. However, I prefer to stay within the ANOVA "style"/ `ezANOVA` environment as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer that I found for now is to use the `mixed` function from `afex` package. `nsim` is the number of samples to bootstrap, `seed` acts like `set.seed()` for reproducibility.

```
library(afex)

mixed(
  formula = rt ~ group*flank + (1 | subnum),
  data=ANT,
  method = "PB",
  args_test = list(nsim = 1000, seed = 123), 
  test_intercept = TRUE,
  type = "II")
```

Results:

```
Model: rt ~ group * flank + (1 | subnum)
Data: ANT
       Effect df       Chisq p.value
1       group  1   10.93 ***   .0010
2       flank  2 1852.17 ***   .0010
3 group:flank  2   16.36 ***   .0010
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, I will be more than happy to hear about other options.